# SQL substring after second occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have strings such as below:

```
Geographical Information & Income: Income - National Classifications: Los Angeles - Low
```

Do you know how can only get "Low" from this? This is difficult for me since I don't know how I can tell substring to start from second "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this string, use string functions like this:

```
declare @s varchar(100) = 'Geographical Information & Income: Income - National Classifications: Los Angeles - Low';

select ltrim(right(@s, charindex('-', reverse(@s)) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the far right word by using `RIGHT`:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(500) = 'Geographical Information & Income: Income - National Classifications: Los Angeles - Low'

SELECT RIGHT(@string,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@string)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid for 2nd index of "-"

```
     Select
            Substr(
          Instr(
                Substr(
                Instr(Substr(string, "-")+1, 
                Length(string)
                            ), 
            "-")+1 , 
            length(string)) from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use trim in combination:

```
select trim(RIGHT ( 'Geographical Information & Income: Income - National Classifications: Los Angeles - Low ' , charindex('-', reverse('Geographical Information & Income: Income - National Classifications: Los Angeles - Low '))-1) )
```

Why ? Well because you can have a case like this 'test - test - word  '
Cheers!